# Dose The abstract class have attributes?

Tags: uml, abstract, analysis

My Question in Analysis and design system with UML Methodology 
Dose the abstract class have attributes or just Methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can have both.
If at least one method is abstract, a class is abstract.